# How to measure the execution time with Java

Tags: java, execution-time

I'm trying to print the execution time of the code below, but it's always giving me 0 milliseconds. I found this code online and wanted to measure the execution, so I added a few lines at the bottom.

Java:

```
class MergeSort {
void merge(int nums[], int left, int m, int right) {
    int n1 = m - left + 1;
    int n2 = right - m;

    int Left_part_arra[] = new int[n1];
    int Right_part_arra[] = new int[n2];

    for (int i = 0; i < n1; ++i)
    Left_part_arra[i] = nums[left + i];
    for (int j = 0; j < n2; ++j)
    Right_part_arra[j] = nums[m + 1 + j];

    int i = 0,
    j = 0;

    int k = left;
    while (i < n1 && j < n2) {
        if (Left_part_arra[i] <= Right_part_arra[j]) {
            nums[k] = Left_part_arra[i];
            i++;
        } else {
            nums[k] = Right_part_arra[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }

    while (i < n1) {
        nums[k] = Left_part_arra[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }

    while (j < n2) {
        nums[k] = Right_part_arra[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }
}

// merge()
void sort(int nums[], int left, int right) {
    if (left < right) {
        // Find the middle point
        int m = (left + right) / 2;

        // Sort first halve
        sort(nums, left, m);
        // Sort second halve
        sort(nums, m + 1, right);

        // Merge the sorted halves
        merge(nums, left, m, right);
    }
}

// Method to test above
public static void main(String args[]) {
    MergeSort ob = new MergeSort();
    int nums[] = {
        7,
        -5,
        3,
        2,
        1,
        0,
        45
    };
    System.out.println("Original Array:");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nums));
    ob.sort(nums, 0, nums.length - 1);
    System.out.println("Sorted Array:");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nums));

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Merge took: " + (end - start) + " milliseconds");
}
}
```

Comment: You can't "calculate" big-O complexity by doing timing measurements. You do it by analyzing how the algorithm behaves as the number (or the size) of the inputs grows. And big-O complexity won't tell you how long an algorithm will run for - it tells you how the runtime changes as the input changes.

Comment: This is (sort of) measuring time, not time complexity.

Comment: The units of Big-O are not milliseconds. Unclear what you're asking. There is no Big-O or time complexity here. Don't misuse standard terminology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for this to work, this line:

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

should be before this line:

```
ob.sort(nums, 0, nums.length-1);
```

Also, keep in mind this is measuring Time and **not** Time Complexity

Comment: Exactly my thoughts :-) maybe one detail: big o needs to be computed / derived, you don't "measure it theoretically"

Comment: long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
ob.sort(nums, 0, nums.length - 1);
long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println("Merge took: " + (end - start) + " milliseconds");

Merge took: 0 milliseconds

I'm still getting 0 value, any thoughts?

Comment: @kpAtCh Your code might be taking less than 1 milisecond to complete, try increasing the input size or using `System.nanoTime();` instead of `System.currentTimeMillis(); `

Answer (score 1):

Your `start` and `end` are right next to each other, if you want to time something, start should be before the operation that you are timing, and end after.  In this case they should sandwich `ob.sort();`

As a side note, timing a sort is usually more informative when the collection being sorted is large.  Many slow sort algorithms may seem to perform equally well, or even better than, a more efficient algorithm when tested on a small sample size.

Comment: long start = System.currentTimeMillis(); ob.sort(nums, 0, nums.length - 1); long end = System.currentTimeMillis(); System.out.println("Merge took: " + (end - start) + " milliseconds"); Merge took: 0 milliseconds I'm still getting 0 value, any thoughts?

Comment: I'm not familiar with getting time in Jave, but I would say try a larger array.